# Service override when component is based on interface produces There is already a component with that name

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

From[here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Supplying_the_component_for_a_dependency_to_use_Service_override_9) I understand how to specify a component, but what if the component implements an interface that itself is resolved in the container?

I use three interfaces: `IDBViewerModel`, `IMembershipModel` and `IMongoConnection`. I wish to resolve `IDBViewerModel` to `DBViewerModel` and `IMembershipModel` to `MembershipModel`. Easy enough.

However, both `DBViewerModel` and `MembershipModel` expect `IMongoConnection` as contructor-injected component - and the two components are NOT the same so I want to use service override.

My example is as follows. `DBViewerModel : IDBViewerModel` and `MembershipModel : IMembershipModel,` where `DBViewerModel` and `MembershipModel` constructors expect an injected component and look something like:

```
DBViewerModel(IMongoConnection uaxDB)
MembershipModel(IMongoConnection dataDB)
```

Now I have `MongoConnection : IMongoConnection` and `MongoConnection` looks like:

```
public MongoConnection(string DBlocation, string DB)
```

I wish to supply DBlocation and DB parameters differently for injection of a `MongoConnection` component into `DBViewerModel` and `MembershipModel`. So I try:

```
 container.Register(Component
               .For<IDBViewerModel>()
               .ImplementedBy<DBViewerModel>()
               .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);

         container.Register(Component
               .For<IMembershipModel>()
               .ImplementedBy<MembershipModel>()
               .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);


container.Register(
           Component.For<IMongoConnection>()
               .ImplementedBy<MongoConnection>()
               .Named("myservice.dataDB")
               .DependsOn(Property.ForKey("DBlocation").Eq(USERmongoURL),
                    Property.ForKey("DB").Eq(USERmongoCollection))
               .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
           Component.For<IMongoConnection>()
               .ImplementedBy<MongoConnection>()
               .Named("myservice.uaxDB")
               .DependsOn(Property.ForKey("DBlocation").Eq(UAXmongoURL),
                    Property.ForKey("DB").Eq(UAXmongoCollection))
               .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,

           Component.For<DBViewerModel>()
               .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("dataDB").Eq("myservice.dataDB")),
           Component.For<MembershipModel>()
               .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("uaxDB").Eq("myservice.uaxDB"))

       );
```

My error message says it all - and yet I don't know how to resolve my dependency chain properly:

> Component DBViewerModel could not be registered. There is already a
>   component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing
>   component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
container.Register(Component
         .For<IDBViewerModel>()
         .ImplementedBy<DBViewerModel>()
         .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
         .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("dataDB", "myservice.dataDB")));

container.Register(Component
         .For<IMembershipModel>()
         .ImplementedBy<MembershipModel>()
         .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
         .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("uaxDB", "myservice.uaxDB")));


container.Register(
       Component.For<IMongoConnection>()
           .ImplementedBy<MongoConnection>()
           .Named("myservice.dataDB")
           .DependsOn(Property.ForKey("DBlocation").Eq(USERmongoURL),
                Property.ForKey("DB").Eq(USERmongoCollection))
           .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
       Component.For<IMongoConnection>()
           .ImplementedBy<MongoConnection>()
           .Named("myservice.uaxDB")
           .DependsOn(Property.ForKey("DBlocation").Eq(UAXmongoURL),
                Property.ForKey("DB").Eq(UAXmongoCollection))
           .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest

   );
```

Comment: I get the following error with rarous suggestion:Error 1 'Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer' does not contain a definition for 'DependsOn' and no extension method 'DependsOn' accepting a first argument of type 'Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Development\MattOzTools\NANIToolkit\Database Viewer\Database Viewer\Database Viewer\Installers\ControllerInstaller.cs 67 11 Database Viewer

Comment: An explanation would be useful.